# What is this "appliance control" power strip?

Tags: electrical

I found the pictured power strip in the cabinet under my kitchen sink. It was mounted to the wall and has an attached wire connected to a metal disk that was mounted to the the cabinet, just under the countertop. The only thing plugged into the power strip was some non-functional under-cabinet lighting whose power cord had been routed through the wall. On the underside of the power strip is a label that says "38AF APPLIANCE CONTROL".

I removed the dead lighting and also pulled out this power strip, along with the attached wire and metal disk. I don't think any of this stuff was serving an important function, but I don't like removing things when I don't even know what they are. Can anyone tell me what this thing is?

[image: Weird power strip]

[image: Jack attacking wire to strip]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A quick search came up with this: [(Amazon)](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01FLBFDK4)

The disk is a touchpad which controls dimming of the lights plugged into the strip.

This took me less than one minute, entering "38AF APPLIANCE CONTROL" into Google. (Actually, I didn't type it, I copied it from your question.) In the future, I'd suggest using a web search before posting.

Comment: I actually searched for it quite a bit before posting, on both Google and on internet retailer websites. But I didn't type the magic letters 38AF. Thanks for your help.